# I can't run my app in iOS 9.3 simulator

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I'm trying to test hello world app with IOS simulator version 9.3, I'm running OSX el captain in VMWare, xcode installed.

in Rad studio Seattle when I chose to run the app on simulator, the run button is disabled. what I'm doing wrong?

entering c in Paserver shows nothing..

Comment: You tagged the question delphi-xe. That version does not support mobile platforms. You mention XE10 in the question but there is no such version. You need to make it very clear what version you actually use.

Comment: I cannot tag xe-10 , stackoverflow refused it. so I just went with that name

Comment: That's right. There is no such version as XE10. What version are you using? Delphi 10 Seattle, or Delphi 10.1 Berlin?

Comment: edited my post, it is Delphi 10 Seattle

Comment: Thanks. I've re-tagged it. Embarcadero certainly confused everybody with their name convention change!

Comment: Are you running OSX in a VM on a Windows host? As far as I know this is not properly supported and there is not proper display driver for such a "Hackintosh" VM. Can you run / debug any Delphi apps in this VM at all? Does a "Hello World" Firemonkey app run on OSX?

Comment: @Olaf Hess yes I'm running OSX in VM on a Windows Host (win10). a friend of my is using this method to test IOS apps in simulator, but with Delphi 10.1 Berlin and working fine, I don't know about OSX programs though. I'm asking about IOS apps to be clear.

Comment: I asked about a normal OSX desktop app to figure out whether there's a general problem in debugging applications running on OSX or only when an iOS app is running in the simulator.